# How to get Redux Form data in another Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

How can i pass the data from redux form, So that i can access that data in App.js?
here is the code i have written using redux-form.after i click on submit the data should be passed from form.js to app.js. and the data should be displayed on page.

here is form.js-

```
const Form=({fields:{name,address}})=>(
  <form>
    <center>
    <div>
      <label>First Name</label>
      <Field type="text" component="input" placeholder="Name" name="name"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Address</label>
      <Field type="text" component="input" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </center>
  </form>
)


export default reduxForm({
  form: 'form',
  fields: ['name', 'address']
})(Form);
```

how can i pass this inputed data to app.js?

Comment: Are you rendering your Redux form from app.js itself

Comment: No i want to call redux form on clicking button at app.js

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you need to do is use `getFormValues` to get the `redux field` values

So in App.js you can have

```
import {getFormValues} from 'redux-form';

..
const App = (props) => {
      var {name, phone} = props.formStates
      console.log(name, phone);
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
         formStates: getFormValues('form')(state) // here 'form' is the name you have given your redux form 
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```

Comment: Check this answer

Comment: Thanks Shubham...How can i redirect to app.js after clicking submit button ?

Comment: you will be rendering the Redux form from some component, pass a handleSubmit function as prop onSubmit to ReduxForm Component and htne in the parents handleSubmit function routeDynamically with `this.props.history.push('/app')`

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

The above mentioned answer is absolutely correct however, when your form component gets unmounted the state may get destroyed and then it will not be available in any other component.To fix this you can add `destroyOnUnmount: false` to your reduxForm wrapper like this

```js
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'form',
  destroyOnUnmount: false, 
})(Form)
```

Now you can get the form data in any component by following the above answer. Hope this helps