# Redux-Form, how to use formValueSelector with dynamic Field names?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I'm using redux form and trying to create a Field component like so:

```
<Rating
  stop={10}
  initialRate={selector(this.props.state, 'age')}
  onRate={(rate) => this.onRateChange(rate)}
  onChange={(value) => { this.changeRate("name", value) } }
/>
<span className="label label-default" id="label-onrate">{this.state.label}</span>

<Field
  name="age"
  type="number"
  component={renderField2}
/>

RateForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'rateForm'
})(RateForm);

const selector = formValueSelector('rateForm');

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RateForm);
```

**The problem I'm having is `initialRate` is not working... the following is not returning a value:**

```
selector(this.props.state, 'age')
```

Because the field name will be dynamic, I need to avoid:

defining the specific field name in mapStateToProps.

What am I doing wrong with redux-form formValueSelector to not provide initialRate with a value?

Comment: which version of redux form do you use

Comment: 6.6.3 is my version of redux form. Is that the issue?

Comment: Are you sure you are passing `state` as a prop to your RateForm Component?

Comment: Can you be a little more specifc about field names being dynamic? Will it be an array of fields? Can you fork https://jsfiddle.net/sherin81/d82a1tao/ and provide a basic sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import { getFormValues } from 'redux-form/immutable'
```

`getFormValues` will return the values saved corresponding to the `form name` provided.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const formState = getFormValues('rateForm')(state)
  console.log('formState...', formState)
  return formState 
}
```

This is working fine for me. I am getting values of all the `Field` component rendered particular to this form i.e `rateForm` in your case.
For more details, you can go [here](http://redux-form.com/6.0.5/docs/api/Selectors.md/).

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> The function returned from `formValueSelector()` has the following
>   structure:
>
> **selector(state:Object, ...field:String)**
>
> ```
>  state : Object [required]
> ```
>
> The global Redux state given to `mapStateToProps`.
>
> ```
>  ...field : String [required]
> ```
>
> The field, or fields, you want to select. If you provide only one
>   field name, the function will return the value of that field. If you
>   provide more than one field name, it will return an object mapping
>   fields to values. If your field are "deep" (i.e. has one or more . in
>   the name), the structure you get back will also be deep. e.g. If your
>   fields are `'a.b'` and `'a.c'`, the resulting structure will be `{ a: { b:'bValue', c: 'cValue' } }.`

In your case you are not returning anything from the mapStateToProps,

You could instead of having a selector in the Rating component, have it in mapStateToProps and use it like

```
<Rating
  stop={10}
  initialRate={selector(this.props.state, 'age')}
  onRate={(rate) => this.onRateChange(rate)}
  onChange={(value) => { this.changeRate("name", value) } }
/>


const selector = formValueSelector('rateForm');

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
      state
  };
};
```

The above example is assuming that `props` are available to the `Rating` component.

Comment: Right but I have a dynamic field name as mention led which is why I can't do that. How can this work w a dynamic field name?

Comment: Do you mean you can have multiple such Rating component fields and in the above case your want initialRating to be equal to age value, In that case check the update

Comment: I will have multiple. I just didn't want to list out all 5+ fields above.

Comment: Thank you, this works but I select Ritesh's answer given it is more performant.

Comment: check this answer too :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44513287/how-to-get-redux-form-data-in-another-component

Answer (score 0):

@Ritesh points me out to the solution:

```
const formName = "form";
const form = reduxForm<MyFormFields, MyFormProps>({form: formName});    

function MyForm() {
   return (
     <div>
        Here your form
     </div
   );

}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
    initialValues: {
    },
    getFormFieldValue: (field: string) => {
        const selector = formValueSelector(formName);
        return selector(state, field);
    }
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
    changeField: (field: string, value: any) => dispatch(change(formName, field, value)),
    resetForm: () => dispatch(reset(formName)),
});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(form(MyForm)));
```

Hope this can be helpful for someone!