# Redux Form State

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

How would I push these values to the employment history state? I am getting the read out in form but not to the initial state?

Should I use formSelector to push values to state? This has been a nightmare for me, as it is 99% finished except for getting everything to push to state. So that I can push everything where it needs to go once form is complete.

```javascript
class EmploymentHistoryQuestion extends Component {

static propTypes = {
  roles: PropTypes.array,
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func,
  driverProfile: PropTypes.object,
  fields: PropTypes.object,
  whenUserCompletedQuestion: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

state = {
  employmentHistory: {
    employerName: '',
    role: '',
    startDate: '',
    endDate: '',
    description: '',
    currentPosition: false,
  },
};

handleChange = (field) => (response, value) => {
  const { employmentHistory } = this.state;
  const { whenUserCompletedQuestion } = this.props;
  console.log(employmentHistory);
  this.setState({
    employmentHistory,
  }, () => {
    if (field === 'startDate' || field === 'endDate') {
      whenUserCompletedQuestion({
       [field]: response.value,
      });
    } else if (field === 'role') {
      whenUserCompletedQuestion({
        [field]: value,
     });
    } else if (field === 'employerName' || field === 'description') {
      whenUserCompletedQuestion({
        [field]: response.target.value,
     });
   }
 });
};

render() {
  const { fields, roles, handleSubmit, driverProfile, ...more } =   this.props;
 return (
  <div className={bem.el('form')}>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field
        name={'employerName'}
        label={translations.translate('driverProfile', 'employerName')}
        component={renderTextField}
        onChange={this.handleChange('employerName')}
        fullWidth
        required
      />
      <div style={{ minHeight: '120px' }}>
        <InputField
          question={'startDate'}
          onChange={this.handleChange('startDate')}

          required
        />
      </div>
      <div style={{ minHeight: '120px' }}>
        <InputField
          question={'endDate'}
          onChange={this.handleChange('endDate')}
          required
        />
      </div>
      <Field
        name={'role'}
        component={renderSelectField}
        value={this.state.role}
        onChange={this.handleChange('role')}
        required
        fullWidth
      >
        {roles.map((role, index) =>
           (<MenuItem
             value={role}
             key={index}
             primaryText={translations.translate('vehicleTypes', role)}
           />)
        )}
      </Field>
      <Field
        name={'description'}
        label={translations.translate('editJob', 'description')}
        component={renderTextArea}
        onChange={this.handleChange('description')}
        fullWidth
      />
    </form>
  </div>
  );
  }
 }

 export default reduxForm({
  form: 'employmentHistory',
 })(EmploymentHistoryQuestion);
```

Comment: you would probably want to do it in handleSubmit function or since redux for already stores this in a redux store you can use it from there when you need it in another component, see this amswer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44513287/how-to-get-redux-form-data-in-another-component

Comment: closer but fields are not console logging. Will have too look deeper