# React Redux - Field onChange returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my component, I have a redux `Field` where all I'm trying to do is all a function when the field gets updated via Datepicker, however when I do that,

```
render() {
  return (
       <Field onChange={this.updateStartDate} name='startDate' component={DatePicker} hintText="Pick the start date" floatingLabelText="Start Day"/>
  );
}
```

And here is my `updateStartDate` function where I'm just logging the output:

```
updateStartDate(event) {
   console.log('change start date', event);
}
```

The only thing I get is this: `change start date {preventDefault: ƒ}` in the console. I've had other instances with a `TextField` where `onChange` gave me what I wanted, but not in this instance. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Why do you need an onChange, its internally handled by the Field Itself, 
 You can check this answer if you just want to get the value in some other function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44513287/how-to-get-redux-form-data-in-another-component

Comment: Well the thing is, I'm not using these fields in the context of a form, I'm just trying to get the value out of the `Field`. I'm not 100% clear how to do that from that answer you linked :/

Comment: Why do you need a Field Component then, you could just have a simpe DatePicker instead.

Comment: Actually, that's perfect. Thankyou :)