# How do I get any form value from anywhere in my app in redux-forms v7

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-form

The closest to doing this is [`reduxForm().getFormState()`](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-getformstate-function-code-optional-) of which it's not well documented

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44513287/how-to-get-redux-form-data-in-another-component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the `formValueSelector` that is exported from redux-form. While you can dive directly into the state tree and pull things out for yourself, using the selector exported by redux-form means that you aren't taking a dependency on any implementation details of redux-form.

You use it like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { formValueSelector } from 'redux-form';

class App extends React.Component {
  // ...
}

const formName = 'myForm'; // Name of form you want
const myFormValueSelector = formValueSelector(formName);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  name: myFormValueSelector(state, 'name') // selects the name field value
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

You can find documentation for this method [here](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/formvalueselector.md/)

Answer (score 1):

Form values will be available on the redux store. You can get it from any app components.

Mini example,

index.js,

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
import App from './src/components';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    form: formReducer,
});

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    <Provider>
, document.querySelector('.root'));
```

app.js,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { change, Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends Component {
    ...
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.forms); // This fill print information about all of your app forms
        return <div />;
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        forms: state.form;
    }
}

export default reduxForm({ 
    form: 'someForm',
})(connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    null
)(App));
```

In app.js, `console.log` will print form data like this,

```
{
    someForm: {...someForm props},
    someOtherForm: {...someOtherForm props},
}
```